# MKMapView goes white after UITableViewCell reloads

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView embedded into the a UITableViewCell. At times, the section gets reloaded. The problem is that the map cell decided to go white all of the sudden when the refresh happens.

Here is the basic code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mapCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Map"];
    [_mapCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [_mapCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [_mapView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_mapCell.contentView addSubview:_mapView];

    [_mapCell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_mapView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mapView)]];
    [_mapCell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_mapView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mapView)]];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_mapCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return _mapCell;
}
```

And the reload code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    });
}
```

[Here is the sample project to demonstrate the problem.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27896159/TESTmapWHITE.zip)

---

Note: JIT for tableview is laggy if used with maps. Hence, I created an iVar for it and init it earlier.

Comment: You forgot to call viewDidAppear's super implementation.

Comment: True, although that was not the reason. (it was a quick write up and I missed it) (Added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections%3awithRowAnimation%3a)

```
reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
Reloads the specified sections using a given animation effect.

- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
Parameters
sections  An index set identifying the sections to reload.
animation A constant that indicates how the reloading is to be animated, for 

The animation constant affects the direction in which both the old and the new section rows slide. For example, if the animation constant is UITableViewRowAnimationRight, the old rows slide out to the right and the new cells slide in from the right.
Discussion
Calling this method causes the table view to ask its data source for new cells for the specified sections. The table view animates the insertion of new cells in as it animates the old cells out. Call this method if you want to alert the user that the values of the designated sections are changing. If, however, you just want to change values in cells of the specified sections without alerting the user, you can get those cells and directly set their new values.
```

Specifically

> The animation constant affects the direction in which both the old
>   and the new section rows slide. For example, if the animation constant
>   is UITableViewRowAnimationRight, the old rows slide out to the right
>   and the new cells slide in from the right.

You are returning the same cell which table view tries to move away through animation also.
This is why the map view disappears.

You would have to use this part to solve

> If, however, you just want to change values in cells of the specified
>   sections without alerting the user, you can get those cells and
>   directly set their new values.

Using `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` also works

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Right on! +1 for very nice write up!

Comment: Thank you!! Been scratching my head on this one!!

Answer (score 1):

It is really strange since your code looks ok. I was able to reload the section and display the cell using this code:

```
[CATransaction begin]; 

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^
{ 
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}];

[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]    
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[CATransaction commit];
```

But this is more a workaround than a fix.

Comment: As work-around, just use [self.tableView reloadData] in place of reloadSections and the CATransaction code.

Comment: Both are definitely workarounds. They, however, will call reloadData which in turns calling other section to be reloaded as well. It might drain resources in the process. Thank you for your input! But +1 for the animation.